# Fstream does not recognise relative path

Tags: c++, visual-studio, file-io

I have a code like this, which is working

```
void savebinds()
    {
        ofstream ofs("C:\\Users\\Raitis\\source\\repos\\Project5\\x64\\Debug\\savedbinds.txt");

        if (ofs.is_open()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < binds.size(); i++)
            {
                ofs << binds[i] << endl;
            }
            ofs.close();
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Unable to write to the file";
        }
    }
```

But strange thing happens, when I change

`ofstream ofs("C:\\Users\\Raitis\\source\\repos\\Project5\\x64\\Debug\\savedbinds.txt");`

to

`ofstream ofs("savedbinds.txt");`

File is in the project directory, have tried to put it everywhere. Still not working. I am using visual studio 2019 and latest windows 10 version

Edit:
Same thing happens with ifstream

Comment: Relative path means relative to the current directory when the program is started. How do you start the program? In any case, if this is for anything more than a toy project: please do not rely on working directory, it's a mess, spreading your files all over the filesystem.

Comment: Copy file savedbinds.txt to C:\Users\Raitis\source\repos\Project5\Project5 first, if you are running from the VC++ ide and your code should work.

Comment: it's like 19 years since I used VS (VS6.0 back then), but often the "execute" command starts the exe where it was compiled, not in project directory. So you can either put extra copy of the txt there (I think as one of build steps, so it will be there even after "clean" and rebuild), or you can check the menus if you can configure the working directory for "execute" (usually it's possible), and target the project dir.

Comment: @Ped7g the default working directory these days is the project directory not the output directory, yes the working directory is configurable